# Open application in windows phone 8.1 by holding button or add app to notification center

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I have application that has to be launched by holding button or adding the app to notification center for easy access, i know its not possible in wp7,8 is there anyway to do it ?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible directly. The user may be able to do something like this by configuring Cortana, but I don't believe that you as a developer can. You may be able to get 'notification center access' by sending local toasts so that you are regularly there, but be prepared to fail certification (as this definitely goes against the toast guidelines) and for your users to despise you.

Comment: @NateDiamond is there sticky notification is available in windows phone 8.1 ?

Comment: I don't believe so. Once they clear their notifications, they're gone. (At least, that's what my experience *using* 8.1 has been).